# How do I start a foreach loop at a particular index in scala?

Tags: scala, loops, foreach

I am new to scala and was wondering as to how do I start a foreach loop at a particular index in scala? My code currently that looks something like this:

```
var i = list.indexOf("three")
for(n <-list){
    /*do some operation*/
}
```

Here the "list" holds a list of Strings ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]. Instead of starting from the begining of the list, I want my for each loop to start operation from the index i and ignore all the vaues before it (i.e only consider the values "four" and "five").

Can somebody please help me here? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `drop`:

```
for (n <- list.drop(i)) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you *could* use `.drop` like the other answer suggests, but that's a wrong thing to do in this case. You end up traversing the head of the list twice, which is inefficient, and inelegant.

You can do the same thing with just a single scan:

```
list
 .dropWhile(_ != "three")
 .tail
 .foreach { n => 
   ...
 }
```